# Function that takes a function with varying arguement lengths

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to create a function in python that accepts a function with an arbitrary number of variables and a parameter n and returns the same function but with 1 added to the nth variable.  An example of this would be given a function such as `d = f(w, x, y, z)` a function call to `func_want(d, 2)` would yield `=> f(w, x, y+1, z)`.  Similarly, if `e = f(x,y)` then `func_want(e, 0) => f(x+1,y)`

I understand how to use `*args` to construct a function that takes a function with varying arguements but I can't seem to figure out how to incorporate a way to 'split up' the variables based on an index (i.e. `n`)

Comment: something like `list(args)`

Comment: It would really help to write your examples in complete Python code, rather than sketchy pseudocode that doesn't quite make sense. If `d = f(w, x, y, z)` is meant to be Python code, then `d` is whatever `f` returned, so there's no way to use `d` to get `f` to be called again differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `*args`, the `args` you get is just a tuple, so `args[n]` is just the nth argument. So, you can do `args[:n] + (args[n]+1,) + args[n+1:]`. Or, maybe more readably, just convert `args` to a list.

For example:

```
def func_want(func, n):
    def wrapper(*args):
        args = list(args)
        args[n] += 1
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

def f(w, x, y, z):
    return w, x, y, z

func_want(f, 2)(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

… will return `(0, 0, 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_want(f, n):
    return f(lambda *args: args[:n] + (args[n]+1,) + args[n+1:])[0]
def f(*args):
    return args
```

Now if we check it for `n=5` we get:

```
>>> new_f = function_want(f, 5)
>>> new_f(0,0,0,0,0,0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```